# Use Python to turn an image into a string using templates

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-recognition

So I have an image that contains a long digit number and the numbers always look the same so I was wondering if I could search a picture of the number for whether any of the templates I have of each number show up, and what order they show up in. Then when its found the order of the templates, it will convert the templates to their corresponding digit and save it into a string. How can I go about this as not sure where to start?

Many thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a fun project idea. Go ahead and get started and let us know if you have any specific questions :-)

Comment: I'm not sure where to start though :(

Comment: Google OCR (Optical character recognition)

Comment: pytesseract is what you are looking for !!